# Can contents of Keytab file be stored and used from Azure Key vault?

Tags: azure, hadoop, kerberos, azure-keyvault, keytab

I have a keytab file used for authentication when trying to connect from Azure Kubernetes Cluster to On-prem hadoop nodes.

Can I store keytab contents in Azure Key vault and read it back?

Comment: You can refer to [Create keytab files for HDFS user accounts](http://doc.isilon.com/onefs/7.1.1/help/en-us/GUID-CFA59DC5-9F79-49CA-9F83-9D524F47B4FC.html), [Generate a Keytab File](https://docs.informatica.com/data-engineering/data-engineering-integration/h2l/1458-faq--authentication-on-hdinsight-with-enterprise-security-p/faq--authentication-on-hdinsight-with-enterprise-security-packag/frequently-asked-questions/how-do-i-generate-a-keytab-file-for-users-.html) and [Creating Keytab Files for Hadoop](https://ambari.apache.org/1.2.5/installing-hadoop-using-ambari/content/ambari-kerb-1-4.html)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you should be able to. It's not implemented out of the box but you could shoe horn it in.  You'd have translate back and forth to unicode using the [keytab as a secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/developers-guide).  You'd still need to create it as a file, and that reverts back to protecting it by permission, and then cleaning it up after your done.  So out of the box it's likely possible but there's a lot of extra manual management.